# Does Visual Studio 2013 support references between projects of different languages?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, reference

I have a VB.Net Windows Application in Visual Studio 2013 (.Net 4.5.2). I'm updating it to call a library that I've written in C#. The solution contains both projects; both are .Net 4.5.2. However, when I add a reference to the C# project, it treats it as a reference to an external dll, not a project reference. This causes 3 problems:

1. When I "Go to Definition" / F12; it doesn't take me to the C# code. Instead it opens the Object Browser to the definition.
2. If I add a new method to my C# library, I can't call that method from my VB code until after I re-compile the C# library.
3. I often create new methods automatically by calling them before they exist and then choosing to automatically create the method in the class. It won't let me do it in this case.

I have tested a few conditions and it seems clear that the problem is that my class library is in C#. I know for sure that in older versions of Visual Studio, I was able to have this same setup without any issues. Did 2013 remove support for this?

Comment: I have a VS2013 solution with a mix of C# and VB.NET projects. They're all .NET 4.5 not 4.5.2 but I doubt that might cause what you're seeing. I am able to move around using goto definition between them. I should mention that I have Resharper installed and it might be adding this functionality.

Comment: I tried installing Resharper to test things out. It seems to add partial support... "Go to definition" works now, and new methods show up in instellisense without recompiling the library. Though it still complains that the new method doesn't exist until after I recompile.